# connect() failed (113: Host is unreachable) while connecting to upstream nginx for aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I know the this question is asked multiple times and not related to aws.

```
2020/07/29 10:23:17 [error] 6#6: *37749 connect() failed (113: Host is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client:
```

I am facing this issue while I have deployed nginx in aws cloud.

**localtion configuration**

```
location /test {
         proxy_pass http://test-service;
         proxy_set_header HOST $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         }
```

**Upstream section like below**

```
upstream test-service {
    server test-service.internal:38102;
    keepalive 10;
}
```

Here `test-service.internal` is my route53 hosted zone entry and it is pointing to some `internal application load balancer` of aws.

When I deploy/restart nginx server, it works well but after few days (around two/three days) it will hang in proxy pass only. When I load html content, it works perfectly but proxy pass call stuck.

Any solution would be helpful?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After long debugging, we found that nginx will cache `test-service.internal` ips. And aws will chang it's internal load balancer's ips.

So nginx cached ips are no more exist. so we need to provide new ips.

**Solution:**

nginx has provided `resolver` directive

```
location /test {
           resolver 10.0.0.2 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
           set $backend_servers test-service.internal;
           proxy_pass http://$backend_servers:38102;
         #proxy_pass http://test-service;
         proxy_set_header HOST $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Connection "";
         }
```

We have changed two things.

1. Added resolver.
2. Removed upstream (resolver is not supported in nginx. nginx-plus support the upstream with resolver)

   ```
   resolver 10.0.0.2 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;    
   set $backend_servers test-service.internal;
   proxy_pass http://$backend_servers:38102;
   ```

Now we are using aws dns server `10.0.0.2` to resolve `test-service.internal` after every 30s