# Docker: nginx trying to connect to wrong IP

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have docker compose file, where there is `web` service (nginx) and `myapp`. When both containers are started/stopped together, it works as expected.

But if my `app` container is killed separately and then started again, sometimes `nginx` fails to connect to it.

Turns out that when you recreate container, docker can assign new internal IP, but nginx will still be expecting old one.

For example, this can make nginx use old IP:

```
docker compose rm -fsv myapp
docker compose up -d
```

And then what you get from nginx:

```
Mar 31 08:46:23 stage web-service[1895072]: 2023/03/31 08:46:23 [error] 20#20: *73 connect() failed (113: Host is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 2.2.2.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.4:8069/", host: "1.1.1.1", referrer: "http://1.1.1.1"
```

When I inspect docker network, I see:

`docker network inspect app_frontend`

```
[
    {
        "Name": "app_frontend",
        "Id": "5cbd40d119485b42c0d6e07983dc3ee8a89d1acf4b1d1ef2aaecf618599adcd5",
        "Created": "2023-03-31T06:22:03.974263439Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "4bef357bd5bc8e03f1b79293214e5b83195e645a1df16388cb7e64fb0ee0641c": {
                "Name": "app-myapp-1",
                "EndpointID": "c295d47dfc4f7c7ef31ee38932bc973a9e7f55db7f764af641e6a46f212d0b36",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a467f6da4f4d888186b381e97ead3dc6b8383911ec2092532e418c9583c691b2": {
                "Name": "app-web-1",
                "EndpointID": "ecf8201a2d48307569413e6dd93f13a38999069280429bf3f619293914284560",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "frontend",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "app",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.17.2"
        }
    }
]
```

Now I workaround, by simply reloading nginx. But I wonder if there is better way to ensure that nginx would automatically resolve this on its own?

UPDATE:

This is my compose file. There is nothing special here. `web` (nginx) reverse proxies `myapp`. The only relevant services should be `web` and `myapp`.

When I stop/start `myapp`, if I inspect docker network, I can see that its IP changed (it sometimes changes, sometimes not).

```yaml
---
version: "3.9"

x-common-variables: &common-variables
  POSTGRES_DB: postgres
  POSTGRES_USER: myapp
  POSTGRES_PORT: 5432

services:
  myapp:
    image: myregistry.io/myorg/my-image:16.0
    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        tag: myapp-service
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - myapp-data:/opt/myapp/data
      - /opt/myapp/.secrets/myapp.conf:/etc/myapp/myapp.conf
      - /opt/myapp/.secrets/POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE:/tmp/POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      MARABUNTA_MIGRATION_FILE: /opt/myapp/myapp.yml
      MARABUNTA_DATABASE: myappdb
      MARABUNTA_DB_USER: myapp
      MARABUNTA_DB_PASSWORD_FILE: /tmp/POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE # pragma: allowlist secret
      MARABUNTA_DB_HOST: db
      MARABUNTA_MODE: stage
      MARABUNTA_FORCE_VERSION: setup
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
  db:
    # 15.2-alpine3.17
    image: postgres@sha256:53a02ecbe9d18ff6476e6651c34811da39f054424c725fc15d2b480fc3fab877
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql.conf"]
    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        tag: db-service
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - /opt/myapp/.secrets/POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE:/tmp/POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE
      - /opt/myapp/data/postgresql/postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql.conf
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /tmp/POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - backend
  web:
    image: myregistry.io/myorg/nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        tag: web-service
    volumes:
      # Sharing myapp data so nginx can serve it!
      - myapp-data:/opt/myapp/data
      - /opt/myapp/data/nginx/maintenance_logo.png:/usr/share/nginx/html/maintenance_logo.png
      - /opt/myapp/data/nginx/custom_502.html:/usr/share/nginx/html/custom_502.html
      - /opt/myapp/data/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - /opt/myapp/data/certbot/conf:/etc/nginx/ssl/:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - frontend
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        tag: certbot-service
    # Just to list existing certs instead of attempting to configure
    # anything by default.
    command: certificates
    volumes:
      - /opt/myapp/data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw
    networks:
      - frontend

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local
  myapp-data:
    driver: local

networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
```

P.S. Looks like similar issue [connect() failed (113: Host is unreachable) while connecting to upstream nginx for aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63154521/connect-failed-113-host-is-unreachable-while-connecting-to-upstream-nginx-f) but not related with docker network.

Comment: Do you have a [mcve], maybe at least the `docker-compose.yml` file?  I have run into a not-Docker-specific problem with Nginx in the past that it doesn't respect DNS TTLs and you have to restart it if the DNS mappings change and that sounds like it could be your problem here.

Comment: @DavidMaze yeah, sounds like it could be this problem. I guess it does not matter whether its docker, what important is whether IP changes and nginx is not aware of it. I will post my compose file.